# CSS in HTML Helper - only override width on certain HTML Helpers

Tags: css, html-helper

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ResetDayComponent.WeightedAverageMethodID, DropDownData.AveragingMethodList(), "", new { @class = "multipleReset", propertyName = "ResetDayComponent.WeightedAverageMethodID", onchange = "UpdateField(this);" })%>
```

So I have this HTML Helper. Basically, I want to be able to change the width of the dropdown, but other ones that use the same CSS class `multipleReset`, I don't want to do it. I basically want to be able to have sort of a CSS "parameter". But I don't know if that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always add a second CSS class, and provide the additional style information there.

```
@class = "multipleReset dropDown"
```

Comment: Wow I didn't even know you could do that